# I have two columns of timestamps that are in different tables

Tags: sql, time, timestamp, datediff

I have data from two different tables: `addmissions` and `procedures`. I need to extract the `admittime` column from the `admissions` table and the `starttime` column from the procedures table. I would like to return only the dates where the patients procedure started within two days of their admit time.

the date formats are in the TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIMEZONE format (e.g. `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS`)

so far I have the code to extract all patient records which include the admittime, starttime, icd9_code, and the subject_id

SELECT admissions.admittime,procedureevents_mv.starttime,procedures_icd.icd9_code,admissions.subject_id,procedureevents_mv.subject_id,procedures_icd.subject_id
FROM ((admissions
INNER JOIN procedureevents_MV ON admissions.subject_id=procedureevents_mv.subject_id)
INNER JOIN procedures_icd ON admissions.subject_id=procedures_icd.subject_id);

this code executes perfectly, but when i need to narrow the results to show only the patient records which include only the patients whose starttime occurred within two days of the admittime.

the first admittime in the table is 2153-09-03 07:15:00 and the first starttime is 2157-10-21 12:15:00

my query results would need to remove this row of data from the executed query due to the years being different. some of the other rows only vary in months,days, or times. Each row is different and only the times within 2 days of eachother are relevent.

Comment: Edit your question and provide (1) sample data; (2) desired results; (3) a tag for the database you are using.

Comment: Join your tables using whatever (`patient_id`?) and add `where procedure.ts_col between admission.ts_col and admission.ts_col + interval '2' day`. Of course you might need to change the interval calculation to match your DBMS functionality.

Comment: I am unable to share the physical data due to it being based on real hospital patients. My desired results are to find the subject_id of each patient whos procedure (starttime) occurred within two days of being admitted to the hospital (admittime).